# Can I use team city without source control

Tags: teamcity

I want to start a certain build based on another builds artifacts.
Meaning, we run an integration build, and I want to be able to start the build of an installer based on the integration build's artifacts.

So I created another sub project. That needs source control. But I don't want to update the working set.

In CC.Net there was a source control option which was basically just "file system".

Can I run a team city sub project without source control?

Comment: snapshot dependency comes to mind

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run a teamcity target without source control. There is no technical restriction that stops you from doing it.